# Analog meter jquery with php data

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael, graphael, justgage

I have this sample code for an analog meter in Jquery:

```
 <script>
    var g1;
    window.onload = function(){

        var g1 = new JustGage({
          id: "g1", 
          value: getRandomInt(0, 100), 
          min: 0,
          max: 100,
          title: "Big Fella",
          label: "pounds"
        });

        setInterval(function() {                
            g1.refresh(getRandomInt(50, 500));
        }, 2500);
    };
</script>

<div id="g1"></div>
```

Now, I'm trying to change this values according my database information.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery ----

Suppose ajaxurl gives the result of current value then you can use like this

```
 setInterval(function() {    
    $.ajax({url:"ajaxurl",success:function(result){
      g1.refresh(result);
    }});
 }, 2500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of :

```
setInterval(function() {
   g1.refresh(getRandomInt(50, 500));
}, 2500);
```

You have to call an Ajax Request to the server and push the returned data in to the Analog meter:

```
setInterval(function() {
   $.ajax({
      url : '<server address to call>',
      type:'post',
      dataType : 'json',
      success : function(response){
        g1.refresh(getRandomInt(response.value1, response.value2));
      }
  });
}, 2500);
```

Now when the call comes to Server do whatever manipulation you want to do with the data of database and return the data in JSON format.

But make sure you are returning JSON from server and that too with two keys **"value1"** and **"value2"**

Comment: My function is:  

   

    setInterval(function() {    
            $.ajax({url:"analog_meter_data.php",success:function(result){
              g1.refresh(result);
            }});
         }, 2500);


But doesn't work :x

Comment: try to print the response first and in the callback : 

 setInterval(function(){  
   $.ajax({
      url:"analog_meter_data.php",
      success:function(result){ 
        //see what is coming here **(Ctrl+Shift+J)**
        console.log(result);
        g1.refresh(result); 
      }
   }); 
 }, 2500);